# Positioning <li> attributes?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I'm curious as to what the best route to take would be in regard to positioning `<li>` attributes. I have taken over the webmaster duties of the previous employee who created the site, which I find much more difficult than editing my own as everyone has a different way of going about things.

The issue I have is this: 
[image]

In the screenshot I posted, Internet Explorer has pushed the "us" part of "Contact Us" down to the next line. It all appears on one line in Chrome/Firefox, however this needs to be fixed. I could try font changes (as I'm aware that the rendering of fonts in IE has caused the issue), however I also need to add two more menu options.

What I'd like to do is set it up so that no matter the browser, everything would be positioned as it is in the following image:

[image]

The code for the footer navigation menu is a PHP include that currently reads like this:

```
<div id="footer_nav">


    <ul class="footer_nav_list">

            <li class="rightindent">&copy;2014 My Company, LLC&nbsp; &nbsp; All Rights Reserved.</li>

            <li><a href="index.php">HOME&nbsp;|&nbsp;</a></li>

            <li><a href="solutions.php">PAGE 1&nbsp;|&nbsp;</a></li>

            <li><a href="solutions2.php">PAGE 2&nbsp;|&nbsp;</a></li>

            <li><a href="support.php">SUPPORT&nbsp;|&nbsp;</a></li>

            <li><a href="careers.php">CAREERS&nbsp;|&nbsp;</a></li><br />

            <li><a href="contact.php">CONTACT US&nbsp;|&nbsp;</a></li>

            <li><a href="sitemap.php">SITEMAP&nbsp;|&nbsp;</a></li>                      

     </ul>     


</div>
```

This include is calling a CSS style sheet that consists of the following code:

```
html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, embed, 
figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, 
menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
border: 0;
font-size: 100%;

vertical-align: baseline;
}
/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */
article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, 
footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
display: block;
}
body {
line-height: 1;
}
ol, ul {
list-style: none;
}
blockquote, q {
quotes: none;
}
blockquote:before, blockquote:after,
q:before, q:after {
content: '';
content: none;
}
table {
border-collapse: collapse;
border-spacing: 0;
}

/* STRUCTURE BEGINS */
#footer_nav {
background-color: #2f2f2f;
background-image: url(../images/productsMain/footerBg.png);
background-repeat: repeat-x;
width: 940px;
padding-right: 30px;
padding-bottom: 20px;
padding-left: 30px;
float: left;
}
#footer_nav .footer_nav_list {
font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-size: 11px;
color: #999;
list-style-type: none;
padding-top: 35px;
}
#footer_nav .footer_nav_list ul {
text-decoration: none;
display: inline;
list-style-type: none;
margin-top: 15px;
}
#footer_nav .footer_nav_list li  {
display: inline;
}
#footer_nav .footer_nav_list li a {
color: #999;
text-decoration: none;
padding-top: 25px;
padding-left: 2px;
}
#footer_nav .footer_nav_list li a:hover {
color: #FFF;
}
#footer_nav .footer_nav_list .rightindent {
padding-right: 25px;
}
```

Everything I try keeps backfiring, and as this footer appears on every page, it leaves little room for trial and error outside of my localhost.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `<br/>` after the CONTACT US `<li>`.  See this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4Czs4/1/  Also, you may run into the problem again after adding more elements to the footer, so I've set `width: 100%` in your css.  You can delete this line and uncomment the old `width: 940px;`.

Edit: Updated fiddle for what I think you want: http://jsfiddle.net/4Czs4/2/  It should render the way you need it in IE.  I'd still take out the `<br/>`, and let it roll over if it needs to.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time, I appreciate it more than you know

Comment: It looked perfect in jsfiddle but not so when I tested it in my actual file... this ones a brain tickler lol

Comment: How's it look on the site?  You could PM me a link or post it here if need be.